Extra "padding" on text is showing only in Chrome
The language menu (specifically the Arabic option) has goofy ahh padding that I never asked for, unless the language is currently set to Arabic. This is only happening in Chrome and not Safari.
I've tried modifying the CSS, and the JavaScript, and changing the font but it still doesn't fix anything.
Screenshot
I expected Chrome to not add random amounts of padding. Just like how the options for Japanese, Korean, and Chinese have the correct amount of padding, the Arabic button should too.
Edit: This also appears to only happen on chromeOS. It works properly on Windows in Chrome and IE.
Relevant JavaScript for handling the UI
// Stack Overflow Version (CC License)
// While I cannot prevent you from doing so,
// Please do not use this to impersonate me or steal my website design


setTimeout(function () {
    var wb = document.querySelector('.options-language');
    var click = document.querySelector('.website-options-language');
    var le = Languages.Current();
    var auto_div = document.createElement('div');
    var kk = document.createElement('p');
    var zi = document.createElement('img');
    zi.src = '...';
    auto_div.appendChild(zi);
    wb.appendChild(auto_div);
    auto_div.appendChild(kk);
    // IRRELEVANT: automatic language detection removed
    // along with a horizontal line that was added for UI effect
    // This is where all the languages are stored
    window.Languages.All().forEach(function (lang) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = 'options-item';
        var i = document.createElement('img');
        i.src = lang.flag;
        div.appendChild(i);
        var k = document.createElement('p');
        k.innerText = lang.name;
        if(le === lang.id) {
            div.className = 'options-item options-item-selected';
        }
        div.appendChild(k);
        wb.appendChild(div);
        div.onclick = function () {
            if(le !== lang.id || Languages.IsAuto()) {
                Languages.SetLang(lang.id);
            }
        }
    });
    // controls hiding and showing of language menu
    // uses display: none (nothing could affect text)
    // I do not believe this is relevant
},10)

Relevant CSS code
.options {
    top: 54px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    height: fit-content;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 54px - 16px - 8px);
    padding: 8px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.679);
    color: black;
}

.options-category {
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.options-item img {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
}

.options-item p {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 256px;
}

.options-item-link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.options-item {
    width: 284px;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    font-size: 21px;
}


html:not(.text-rtl) .options-item {
    flex-direction: row;
}

html.text-rtl .options-item {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}


I checked the website on Chrome itself, and I don't see the issue there. It looks fine. Maybe try clearing cache.

Works fine on macOS in both Safari and Chrome. So yes, looks like the problem must be limited to ChromeOS. Are you running the latest version? If so, report it as a bug.

That's likely not a "padding", but an issue with the rendering of that particular text in the chosen, resp. actually used, font.

@CBroe I changed the font and this still remains. It also did render normally if I had the website's language set to Arabic.

@DarkBee Sorry, I wasn't aware you were couldn't just link a website

@themirrazz That's because when the external resource, e.g. website goes offline, the question would be invalidated

"It also did render normally if I had the website's language set to Arabic" - and what happens, when you set it just for this one single navigation item?
